# How traveling salesman problem is implemented uaing kruskal's algorithm such that node is inserted only at beginning or at end

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement TSP using kruskal's algorithm such that when inserting, the insertion goes to the beginning or the end. Meaning there is only chain of nodes and no node is connected to more than 2 nodes.

Here is the pseudocode for above illustrated idea. I want to implement End(u) and End(v).But I can't seem to find how these End(v) and End(u) would be implemented. Can anyone help? [image: Psuedocode image]
here is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define edge pair<int, int>

class Graph {
   private:
  vector<pair<int, edge> > G;  // graph
  vector<pair<int, edge> > T;  // mst
  int *parent;
  int V;  // number of vertices/nodes in graph
   public:
  Graph(int V);
  void AddWeightedEdge(int u, int v, int w);
  int find_set(int i);
  void union_set(int u, int v);
  void kruskal();
  void print();
};
Graph::Graph(int V) {
  parent = new int[V];

  //i 0 1 2 3 4 5
  //parent[i] 0 1 2 3 4 5
  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    parent[i] = i;

  G.clear();
  T.clear();
}
void Graph::AddWeightedEdge(int u, int v, int w) {
  G.push_back(make_pair(w, edge(u, v)));
}
int Graph::find_set(int i) {
  // If i is the parent of itself
  if (i == parent[i])
    return i;
  else
    // Else if i is not the parent of itself
    // Then i is not the representative of this set,
    // so we recursively call Find on its parent
    return find_set(parent[i]);
}

void Graph::union_set(int u, int v) {
  parent[u] = parent[v];
}
void Graph::kruskal() {
  int i, uRep, vRep;
  sort(G.begin(), G.end());  // increasing weight
  for (i = 0; i < G.size(); i++) {
    uRep = find_set(G[i].second.first);
    vRep = find_set(G[i].second.second);
    if (uRep != vRep) {
      T.push_back(G[i]);  // add to tree
      union_set(uRep, vRep);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that a minimum-spanning tree (or forest) is not a solution to TSP, only an initial upper-bound ( https://www.quora.com/Does-the-Kruskals-algorithm-solve-always-the-traveling-salesman-problem ) so your code as-is cannot solve TSP problems.

Comment: How it should be modified such that it fulfills the psuedocode?

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Dai The pseudo-code linked is a modification of Kruskal and doesn't produce an MST. It slightly modifies Kruskal logic to produce an open-loop TSP route, but it's an approximation, not guaranteed to be the shortest Hamiltonian path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep an unordered_set of vertex keys to keep track of which vertices are currently at the end of any chain in the solution forest being generated (as for Kruskal TSP you can't add edges to the middle of any chain). Let's call this set of end nodes `unordered_set<int> end`. So, in your `kruskal` function, I would just name `int u = G[i].second.first` and `int v = G[i].second.second` and then extend your `uRep != vRep` check  to `uRep != vRep && end.contains(u) && end.contains(v)`.

You also have to maintain this `end` set of course. You should first initialize it to contain every vertex key. Then, every time you add a new edge you will have to remove one, both, or neither of the involved vertices from the `end` set. Specifically, remove from `end` any vertex from the newly added edge which was already in your solution (because in that case it will no longer be an endpoint).

For example, if you have a chain

```
2 - 3 - 4
```

in the forest already, then when you add the edge `[1 - 2]` to produce the chain

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
```

you need to remove `2` from `end`.

If you already have `1 - 2` and `3 - 4` in the solution and you're adding `2 - 3`, both `2` and `3` would need to be removed from `end`.

And if neither of the involved vertices of the edge being added were yet in the solution, then you can leave them both in `end`.

I think the easiest way to perform this logic would just be to create a set of vertices tracking which have been added to the solution and to add to it right after you push a new edge to the solution. That way you can just do a simple lookup before you add new edges on if either of its endpoints are already in the solution (and remove them from `end` whenever that's the case).

Assuming the rest of your kruskal's implementation is good, those are the only changes you have to make to have it produce a (possibly sub-optimal) solution to open-loop TSP.